# How to manage std::list elements as references?

Tags: c++, reference

I have the following code:

```
struct Foo {
    int var1;
    int var2;


    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Foo& s){
        return os << "[Foo] " << s.var1 << "," <<  s.var2 ;
    }
};

int main() {
    Foo foo;
    foo.var1 = 1;
    foo.var2 = 2;
    std::list<Foo> list;
    list.push_back(foo);

    Foo &foo2 = list.front();
    foo2.var2 = 5;

    std::cout << "foo (" << &foo << "): " << foo << std::endl;
    std::cout << "foo2 (foo from list) (" << &list.front() << "): " << foo2 << std::endl;
}
```

I want both `foo` and `foo2` to reference the same object. So when I assign `5` to `foo2.var2`, I would want to modify `foo.var2` as well. Yet, as we can see in the following output this is not happening:

```
foo (0x7fffffffe140): [Foo] 1,2
foo2 (foo from list) (0x61ac30): [Foo] 1,5
```

What would be the correct way to do that?

Comment: Just to raise the warning... you'll have to make sure that your list will outlive all of the elements that you put into it, or you'll end up making dangling references.  (Same issues as if you were storing pointers into the container)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When you use `push_back` to insert elements into a list, `push_back` creates a copy which is inserted into the list. A solution is to use a [`std::reference_wrapper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) instead as the underlying type of the list, like

```
std::list<std::reference_wrapper<Foo>> lst;
```

and then push into it like

```
lst.push_back(foo);
```

Here is a super simple example that shows you how it works:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

int main() 
{
    int i = 42;
    std::list<std::reference_wrapper<int>> lst;

    lst.push_back(i);           // we add a "reference" into the list
    lst.front().get() = 10;     // we update the list
    std::cout << i;             // the initial i was modified!
}
```

[<kbd>Live on Coliru</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b615243802938ad9)

You need the `reference_wrapper` since you cannot simply create a list of references, like `std::list<Foo&>`. Alternatively, you can use pointers, but I find the `reference_wrapper` approach more transparent.

In the simple example above note the need to use [`std::reference_wrapper::get()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper/get) to obtain the underlying reference, as the `reference_wrapper` is on the left hand side of the assignment operator and hence won't be implicitly converted to `int` via [`std::reference_wrapper::operator T&`.

Below is your full working code modified to use `reference_wrapper`s:

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fb1fd67996d6e5e9

Comment: `std::reference_wrapper<T>` *is* implicitly convertible to `T&`; however, I'm not sure if that would be considered in resolving an `operator=` overload, and even if so there would be a good chance of `reference_wrapper`'s copy constructor to make it ambiguous.  The implicit conversion is more useful if passing to a function taking a reference.

Comment: @DanielSchepler You're right, in fact the assignment operator will try the conversion on its right side, not on the left, so it won't work (the compiler will try to convert `10` to a `reference_wrapper`).

Comment: Which I think would resolve to the explicitly deleted constructor `reference_wrapper(T&&) = delete`, and therefore cause a compiler error.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Exactly, was just playing around with it and can confirm.

Answer (score 4):

Your `std::list<Foo>` contains actual `Foo` objects.  When you call `list.push_back(foo)`, it makes a *copy* of `foo`.  You are then declaring `foo2` to reference that *copied* object, not the original object.  That is why `foo` is not updated when the members of `foo2` are changed.

Try using pointers instead:

```
int main() {
    Foo foo;
    foo.var1 = 1;
    foo.var2 = 2;

    std::list<Foo*> list;
    list.push_back(&foo);

    Foo *foo2 = list.front();
    foo2->var2 = 5;

    std::cout << "foo (" << &foo << "): " << foo << std::endl;
    std::cout << "foo from list (" << foo2 << "): " << *foo2 << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For that you'll need reference semantics instead of value semantics. The most straightforward way to implement reference semantics is through pointers. Only some small changes in your example will do it:

```
struct Foo {
    int var1;
    int var2;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Foo& s){
        return os << "[Foo] " << s.var1 << "," << s.var2 ;
    }
};

int main() {
    auto foo = std::make_unique<Foo>();
    
    foo->var1 = 1;
    foo->var2 = 2;

    // We want a non owning observer of foo
    auto& foo2 = *foo;

    std::list<std::unique_ptr<Foo>> list;
    
    // The ownership of foo is moved into the container
    list.emplace_back(std::move(foo));

    // Another non owning observer
    auto& foo3 = *list.front();
    foo3.var2 = 5;

    // foo is null here, since we moved it in the container, but we have foo2
    std::cout << "foo (" << &foo2 << "): " << foo2 << std::endl;

    std::cout << "foo from list (" << list.front().get() << "): " << foo3 << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you change your output to this:

```
std::cout << "foo " << foo << std::endl;
std::cout << "front " << list.front() << std::endl;
std::cout << "foo2 " << foo2 << std::endl;
```

You'll find the output looks like this:

```
foo [Foo] 1,2
front [Foo] 1,5
foo2 [Foo] 1,5
```

Indeed, when you got a reference, then set `foo2`, you did change the front of the list!  The surprise here is that the front of the list is no longer equal to `foo`.  When you push something into a list, it puts a copy in that list, not a reference.